# complex bash functions: correct usage?

Tags: bash, function, pipe

I'm interested in automating daily tasks. Until recently, every part of one of my scripts was running smoothly. But now I was trying to implement zenity and everything fell apart. Now I'm hoping you can take a look what I'm doing wrong.

Soo, coming to a point: I'm having a cruel bash script, looking like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

dosomething () {
  # code
  echo $1 >> ~/test.txt # For debugging
  $1 & # ← Important line
  # more code
}

main () {
  # other code
  dosomething "/usr/bin/rsync $rsync_options" # ← Call it "do_1"
  dosomething "/usr/bin/find $findme_path -iname \"*.gpx\" -print0 | xargs -0 $other_command" # ← Call it "do_2"
  # another code
}

( main | (zenity --progress $zenity_options || $still_another_command ) &
```

What (should) happen: The output of main is piped to zenity (progress bar). main does not really execute any command, but calls dosomething with a parameter, which contains the command to be executed. dosomething executes the command.

What really happens: The "echo" part of dosomething works like expected. After the script has been executed, the commands in do_1 and do_2 correctly appear in ~/test.txt. (If I copy&pasted the contents of ~/test.txt in my terminal, every command was executed with the expected results.)
The "Important line" of "do_1" is executed with the expected results. But the "Important line" of "do_2" seems to have no effect. At least, I can see no effects of $other_command after executing the script.

I hope you can at least understand what I mean. It would be very kind of you if you gave me a hint what goes wrong in here.

Comment: change the shebang to `#!/bin/bash -x` and run it again, look at the output!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: see [BashFAQ #50](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050).

Long answer: When bash parses a line, it parses quote marks and command delimiters (`|` etc) before doing variable substitution; as a result, then it runs `$1 &` in the function, the quote marks  and pipe in $1's value never get parsed, they're just passed on to the command (usr/bin/find in this case) as part of an argument.  Net result: it's actually running the equivalent of `/usr/bin/find $findme_path -iname '"*.gpx"' -print0 '|' xargs -0 $other_command"`.

Normally, in cases like this, I'd recommend passing the command as a series of words (i.e. have the function run `"$@" &`, and call it as `dosomething /usr/bin/find $findme_path -iname "*.gpx" -print0` but even that won't handle the pipe in the command -- it'll still be treated as just another argument.

One possibility is to use `eval`.  This should be avoided if at all possible, because `eval` is a good way to create scripting bugs -- massive bugs, subtle bugs, incomprehensible bugs, security bugs...  It adds an additional layer of parsing to *everything* in the command line, which means that, for example, if you're trying to operate on a file named `Fred's file.txt` it'll take that apostrophe as a quote mark and get very confused.  Operating on files that happen to contain back-quotes is too horrible to contemplate.  Basically, it's bad news.

After a quick look at the actual script, what I'd recommend is a mix of strategies: hide as much as possible of the command complexity in shell functions, so you aren't trying to pass pipes and redirects into the `dosomething` function, then use the series-of-words approach I mentioned earlier.  For the script in the question, I'd do:

```
#!/bin/bash

dosomething () {
  # code
  printf "%q " "$@" >> ~/test.txt # this gives a much better idea what's being done than echo $1 would
  "$@" &
  # more code
}

# hide the pipeline in a shell function
find_and_do_something () {
  /usr/bin/find "$1" -iname "*.gpx" -print0 | xargs -0 $other_command
}

main () {
  # other code
  dosomething /usr/bin/rsync $rsync_options
  dosomething find_and_do_something "$findme_path"
  # another code
}

( main | (zenity --progress $zenity_options || $still_another_command ) &
```

That means your log file won't have the details of the pipe that's being executed, just `find_and_do_something /whatevers/in/findme_path`, but at least it'll work.

Comment: Short reply: Thanks. Long reply: Wow, I think you did it! For an amateur, this one is hidden really well. Good job! Also Thank you for the BashFAQ, I've learned a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Where do you define `$other_command`? Also, note that you're missing an ending parenthesis at the end (`main` opens a parenthesis that is not closed).

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply. I didn't copy&paste my real code in here – it's too long. Sorry for forgetting the parenthesis in here. If I copied&pasted the part between the part in do_2 (after do_something) into terminal, everything runs fine.

Comment: turn on the shell debugging, i.e. `set -vx`. Then you may see that vars or other syntax are not functioning as you think they should. Also some writers say it is better to use `{ ... ; }` for pipelined processes instead of `(...)`. (note that a terminating ';' before each closing '}' is critical) Good luck.